# Only the distinct values after a group by in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct, sql-server-2014

Here is the sample of the data:

```
 ID     Value   NumPeriod 
 ------------------------     
 1681642    596.8   2 
 1681642    596.8   3 
 1681663    445.4   2
 1681663    445.4   3 
 1681688    461.9   3 
 1681707    282.2   3 
 1681724    407.1   3
 1681743    467     2 
 1681743    467     3 
 1681767    502     3
```

I want to group by the [ID] and take only the distinct values of [Value] within each group and take the "first" distinct [Value] according to [NumPeriod]. So the result would look something this:

```
 ID     Value   NumPeriod 
 -------------------------     
 1681642    596.8   2 
 1681663    445.4   2
 1681688    461.9   3 
 1681707    282.2   3 
 1681724    407.1   3
 1681743    467     2 
 1681767    502     3
```

So I though something like this would work, but no luck:

```
select 
    ID, distinct(Value), NumPeriod
from 
    MyTable
group by 
    ID, Value, NumPeriod
order by 
    ID, NumPeriod
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `distinct` is not a function.  It is an "adjective" that primarily modifies `SELECT` and `COUNT()`.  Banish the thought of using it as if it were a function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a ranking function and a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value, NumPeriod,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NumPeriod ASC)
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT ID, Value, NumPeriod
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ID, Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to change is where you call distinct.
Try this:

```
select distinct ID, Value, NumPeriod
from MyTable
group by ID, Value, NumPeriod
order by ID, NumPeriod
```